Не работает отправка голосовых сообщений в боте Telegram на aiogram
Не могу отправить гс в боте пользователю.
    # Отправка аудио ответа пользователю
    voice_file = InputFile(ogg_path)
    await bot.send_voice(chat_id=message.chat.id, voice=voice_file)
    logging.info("Голосовое сообщение отправлено")

Выдает такую ошибку, что-то про абстрактный класс. Файл в ogg_path существует.
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile with abstract method read

Пробовала использовать BufferedInputFile и ничего не сработало.

Используйте FSInputFile вместо InputFile, предварительно импортировав его from aiogram.types import FSInputFile. Пример будет таким:
@router.message()
async def send_voice(message: Message):
    voice_file = FSInputFile('1.ogg')
    await message.answer_voice(voice_file)

